# My $_SESSION variable will not hold its value. Any Ideas on why?

Tags: php

I want it to increment and decrement the value in `$_SESSION['selection']`.
Mousedown on next form results in: "*The session is 1*".
Mousedown on previous form results in "*The session is -1*".

Here is the code:

```
  <?php

    if (isset($_POST['next'])) {
      displaynext();
    }
    else if (isset($_POST['previous'])) {
      displayprevious();
    }
    else {
      session_start();
      echo "session started";
      $_SESSION['selection'] = 1;
    }

    function displaynext() {
      $_SESSION['selection'] = $_SESSION['selection'] + 1;
      echo "The session is $_SESSION[selection]";
    }

    function displayprevious() {
      if ($_SESSION['selection'] != 1) {
        $_SESSION['selection'] = $_SESSION['selection'] - 1;
      }
      echo "The session is $_SESSION[selection]";
    }

    ?>

    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
      <input type="submit" name="previous" value="Previous">
    </form>

    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
      <input type="submit" name="next" value="Next">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the `session_start()` call on the beginning of your file; right after the `<?php` open tag. You also need to do that on every script that you plan to use sessions.

By the way, instead of writing:

```
$_SESSION['selection'] = $_SESSION['selection']-1;
$_SESSION['selection'] = $_SESSION['selection']+1;
```

You can use

```
$_SESSION['selection']--;
$_SESSION['selection']++;
```

Read: [Increment/Decrement operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)

Comment: @tylercomp Don't forget to mark an answer as 'accepted' when it answered your question, by clicking the check icon left of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using `session_start()` on every page you use your session on.

Answer (score 1):

Put the `session_start` call to the beginning of your code, outside of any conditions.

`session_start` needs to be called in every script you're using the session in, not just at the very beginning (ie. the first pageload).

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling `session_start` when moving between pages. Move the call to before the `if` statements, like this:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['next'])) {
  displaynext();
} else if(isset($_POST['previous'])) {
  displayprevious();
} else {
  echo "session started";

  $_SESSION['selection'] = 1;
}
```